# I´m having one error with auth login

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I´ve my form login when I press button login, I get the error

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Open: C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php

My trace

```
11. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php148
10. Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection match
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php1054
9. Illuminate\Routing\Router findRoute
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php1022
8. Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatchToRoute
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php1001
7. Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php775
6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application dispatch
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php745
5. Illuminate\Foundation\Application handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php72
4. Illuminate\Session\Middleware handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php47
3. Illuminate\Cookie\Queue handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php51
2. Illuminate\Cookie\Guard handle
…\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php23
1. Stack\StackedHttpKernel handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php641
0. Illuminate\Foundation\Application run
…\public\index.php49
```

My login form

```
@section('content1')
<div class="span4 offset4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"> <span class="title-login">Login</span> </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-body">
                <!-- Preguntamos si hay un mensaje de error y si hay lo mostramos -->
                @if (Session::has('error')) 
                <div class='alert alert-danger'>{{ Session::get('error') }}</div>
                @endif
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'role' => 'form')) }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('inputusername', 'Username', array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) }}
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            {{ Form::text('inputusername','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce el nombre del usuario', 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus' => 'true')) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('inputpassword', 'password', array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) }}
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            {{ Form::password('inputpassword', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce la contraseña', 'class' => 'form-control'))}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    {{ Form::checkbox('rememberme', true) }}
                                    Recordar contraseña
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group last">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">

                        {{ Form::submit('Sign in', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm')) }}
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
```

My file routes.php I have following it

```
//Nos mostrara el formulario del login
Route::get('login','AuthController@showLogin');
//Validamos los datos de inicio de sesión
Route::post('login','AuthController@postLogin');
```

My AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends BaseController {
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Controlador de la autenticación de usuarios
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * Muestra el formulario para login.
     */
    public function showLogin()
    {
        // Verificamos que el usuario no esté autenticado
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            // Si está autenticado lo mandamos a la raíz donde estara el mensaje de bienvenida.
            return Redirect::to('hello');
        }
        // Mostramos la vista login.blade.php (Recordemos que .blade.php se omite.)
        return View::make('admin.login');
    }
    /**
     * Valida los datos del usuario.
     */
    public function postLogin()
    {
        // Guardamos en un arreglo los datos del usuario.
        $userdata = array(
            'username' => Input::get('inputusername'),
            'password'=> Input::get('inputpassword')
        );
        // Validamos los datos y además mandamos como un segundo parámetro la opción de recordar el usuario.
        if(Auth::attempt($userdata))
        {
            // De ser datos válidos nos mandara a la bienvenida
            return Redirect::to('hello');
        }
        // En caso de que la autenticación haya fallado manda un mensaje al formulario de login y también regresamos los valores enviados con withInput().

        return Redirect::to('login')->with('error', 'Tus datos son incorrectos'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Route::get('hello', function() {
   die("hello"); 
});
```